# Does using a different linker produce different machine code?

Tags: c++, c, linker

If I write a complex program and build it, will the machine code generated at the end of the day be different if I use, say, `ld` vs `lld` vs `gold`?

Comment: You are asking a question like: Driving a Ford or Honda or Toyota is better? Yes, driving each car will be slightly different. `ld vs lld` - by `ld` i guess you mean "The GNU Linker". What linker is `lld`?

Comment: @KamilCuk `lld` is the LLVM linker.

Comment: What do you mean by "different"?  The different object files and libraries are likely to be added to the executable in different orders, so the binaries will be different even if all the code is the same.  If there is any link time code generation then there will definitely be differences.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I meant link time.  Comment edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Linker will not, for example, change the optimization level after a compiler. It very slightly affects the code itself (mostly while it resolves symbol references). But speaking about the structure of the final executable, it may be very different. The same chunks of code and other resources can be rearranged different ways (most obvous is "removing vs keeping dead code").

So binary comparsion of files will find lots of differences, but in terms of machine code (it's structure and behavior) they'll be almost same.

Comment: It seems like you are contradicting yourself saying first *"speaking about the structure of the final executable, it may be very different"* and then *"in terms of machine code (it's structure and behavior) they'll be almost same"*

Comment: Not the "written to file code structure depicted as EB FE DE AD C0 DE", but "inner, actual code structure depicted as a logical graph". First will vary, second will not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it most likely will. It's not correct to assume that linking with different linkers will produce the same machine code.

The simplest thing that can happen is that the order of functions in the final executable can vary arbitrarily from linker to linker, and therefore the machine code used to make relative calls can vary. One linker may decide to put `func_a` at address `0x1000` therefore translating calls to that function to something like `call 0x1000`, while another linker could place the same function at a different address generating for example `call 0x2000`. The final machine code will therefore differ.

On top of that, at least for ELF executables, there really is no rule about how external symbol references should be ordered in the binary or about what machine code should be used for runtime symbol resolution. PLT (Procedure Linkage Table) stubs could be very different from one linker to another.